# Build your first ListView Command Set extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, listviewcommandset

I created my first ListView extension by watching a Microsoft video. The issue I have is I can see the new menu on the top navigation bar:

[image]

However they wont show on the menu bar on the actions (three dot).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `Location` for your `customActions` in `serve.json` file to show it in context menu.

You can set it to:

- `ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.ContextMenu`: Show only on the context menu of the item(s).
- `ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet`: Show on both the context menu and the command bar

[image]

**Documentation**: [More details about serve.json options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api#more-details-about-servejson-options)